# convert Dictionary<string, myClass> to List<double[]> using c# linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary, group-by

I have a dictionary of `<string,Rate>`

where Rate is defined as:

```
class Rate
{
  public string Name { get; set;}
  public int Tier{ get; set;}
  public double Value { get; set;}

  public Rate(string name,int tr,double val)
   { Name = name; Tier = tr; Value = val;}
}
```

I wish to convert this dictionary to List where the List is broken up (grouped by) Tier from Rate above and the double array holds the Values from Rate as well.

```
Rate rate1 = new Rate("One",1,1.1);
Rate rate2 = new Rate("Two",1,2.2);
Rate rate3 = new Rate("Three",2,3.3);
```

so if..

```
Dictionary<string,Rate> rates = new Dictionary<string,Rate> { {rate1.Name,rate1},{rate2.Name,rate2},{rate3.Name,rate3}};


List<double[]> myList = (linq result from Rates separated list of arrays by tier)
```

then myList[0] would countain 1.1 and 2.2, and myList[1] would countain 3.3.

Answers were good but I need to modify question to provide the list sorted by the tier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<double[]> list = rates
            .GroupBy(pair => pair.Value.Class, pair => pair.Value.Value)
            .Select(doubles => doubles.Select(d => d).ToArray())
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! as follow up question what if Class was an integer instead and I wanted  to have the list ordered by Class? What would the linq statement look like?

Comment: Linq (`IEnumerable<T>`)has an extension method called `OrderBy`.

Comment: sure, but where does it go?

Comment: Something like this:
`var ints = new[] { 3, 5, 4 };
            List<int> list = ints.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
            List<int> listDesc = ints.OrderByDescending(i => i).ToList();`

Comment: thanks, I meant where do I add OrderBy to 1st Answer given on top?

Comment: Got it!  List<double[]> myList =  rates.OrderBy(m => m.Value.Tier).GroupBy(pair => pair.Value.Tier, pair => pair.Value.Value)
            .Select(doubles => doubles.Select(d => d).ToArray())
            .ToList();

Answer (score 1):

```
List<double[]> myList = rates.GroupBy(p => p.Value.Tier)
                             .Select(g => g.Select(p => p.Value.Value).ToArray())
                             .ToList();
```